# inline models editor MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

Ola.. I have a problem with editing of few models in table. I have a List of models on page (with foreach), something like

```
<table id="grid-table" >

@foreach (var image in ViewBag.Images)
{
    <tr>

        <td >
            <a href="@Url.Action("ShowFullImage", new { id = @image.ID })" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" title="@image.Description" >
                <img src="@Url.Action("ShowImageThumbneil", new { id = @image.ID })" alt="@image.AlternateText" />
            </a>
        </td>

        <td >
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveImageInfo", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description) <br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AlternateText) <br />
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ID)

                <div id="item-post" >
                    <input title="Подтвердить" type="submit" value="Подтвердить" />
                </div>
            }
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

and I want to have a way to edit ONE model item. In controller I have something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveImageInfo(ImageModel imageModel)
    {
        Image img = _core.GetImageByID(_client, imageModel.ID);
        img.AlternateText = imageModel.AlternateText;
        img.Description = imageModel.Description;

        _core.SaveImageInfo(_client, img);
        return View();
    }
```

but, of course, it's not works.. 
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ID)` with `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)`. Contents of labels are not sent with POST, but contents of hidden fields are..

Comment: here is one more problem. In this model I have ID of image field(Guid) and ID of Gallery, that image includes(GalleryID, Guid too). And when I press "submit" button, in public ActionResult SaveImageInfo(ImageModel imageModel) in imageModel I see GalleryID as ID and Guid.Emty as GalleryID...

Comment: You have some naming issues. The names of properties of ImageModel must be the same as <input> "name" attributes inside your <form> to be connected properly. Since I don't know how your code currently looks like, I can't be more specific than this..

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing a bit, as I don't know exactly what problem you are seeing, but if it is to do with it trying to redirect, following the save, then try changing from:

```
Html.BeginForm
```

to

```
Ajax.BeginForm
```